# Node.JS - Error with Node-gyp and/or ELIFECYCLE while using npm install

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, npm-install, node-gyp

I'm trying to install the npm library "Sharp" but when I try to run the npm install command, I get this in my console:

```
> sharp@0.18.2 install C:\Users\apixe\Documents\GS Bot\Bots\Child\node_modules\sharp
> node-gyp rebuild


C:\Users\apixe\Documents\GS Bot\Bots\Child\node_modules\sharp>if not 
defined npm_config_node_gyp (node 
"C:\Users\apixe\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\bin\node-gyp-
bin\\..\..\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js" rebuild )  else (node "" 
rebuild )
gyp ERR! UNCAUGHT EXCEPTION
gyp ERR! stack Error: Cannot find module 'minimatch'
gyp ERR! stack     at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:485:15)
gyp ERR! stack     at Function.Module._load (module.js:437:25)
gyp ERR! stack     at Module.require (module.js:513:17)
gyp ERR! stack     at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
gyp ERR! stack     at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\apixe\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\install.js:23:17)
gyp ERR! stack     at Module._compile (module.js:569:30)
gyp ERR! stack     at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:580:10)
gyp ERR! stack     at Module.load (module.js:503:32)
gyp ERR! stack     at tryModuleLoad (module.js:466:12)
gyp ERR! stack     at Function.Module._load (module.js:458:3)
gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 10.0.15063
gyp ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Users\\apixe\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\npm\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd C:\Users\apixe\Documents\GS Bot\Bots\Child\node_modules\sharp
gyp ERR! node -v v8.0.0
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.6.2
gyp ERR! This is a bug in `node-gyp`.
gyp ERR! Try to update node-gyp and file an Issue if it does not help:
gyp ERR!     <https://github.com/nodejs/node-gyp/issues>
npm WARN discord.js@11.1.0 requires a peer of bufferutil@^3.0.0 but none was installed.
npm WARN discord.js@11.1.0 requires a peer of erlpack@hammerandchisel/erlpack but none was installed.
npm WARN discord.js@11.1.0 requires a peer of node-opus@^0.2.5 but none was installed.
npm WARN discord.js@11.1.0 requires a peer of opusscript@^0.0.3 but none was installed.
npm WARN discord.js@11.1.0 requires a peer of sodium@^2.0.1 but none was installed.
npm WARN discord.js@11.1.0 requires a peer of libsodium-wrappers@^0.5.1 but none was installed.
npm WARN discord.js@11.1.0 requires a peer of uws@^0.14.1 but none was installed.
npm WARN gsbot@1.0.0 No repository field.

npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 7
npm ERR! sharp@0.18.2 install: `node-gyp rebuild`
npm ERR! Exit status 7
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the sharp@0.18.2 install script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\apixe\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2017-09-02T23_37_17_871Z-debug.log
```

I have done hours of research trying to figure this out but no luck. If anyone can help, I'd be very thankful.